# show matlab figure in c# picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, matlab

I have a dll file from matlab m file that takes a vector (as input) and does some calculations and then plots a histogram from the data in a figure (Figure 1).

I managed to get the calculation's result into different text boxes in the windows form. The problem is in the figure; I saved it as a jpg image using the command:

```
print -djpeg histogram.jpg
```

but each time I click the button to show the figure in the PictureBox it appears separately as a different figure, but the image in the PictureBox is fixed:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile("location where the jpg is saved");
pictureBox2.Image = img;
```

How to update the resulting image from the matlab to be correctly displayed in the C# PictureBox?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `but each time I click the button to show the figure in the PictureBox it appears separately as a different figure, but the image in the PictureBox is fixed:` I am sorry I do not get what you mean with this sentence. You click the button manually after images are exported from matlab dll?

Comment: i have a button when clicked does the following: 1) Store the data in an array. 2) Send that data to the matlab file. 3) Gets the results back to the text boxes and it is supposed to draw the figure in the picture box

Comment: Have you checked that the image is correctly saved by Matlab to the appropriate location? Are you sure the Matlab routine has finished running by the time C# loads in the picture?

Comment: I still am not sure how your system works, but once you read an image to memory by `Image img = Image.FromFile("location where the jpg is saved"); pictureBox2.Image = img;`, it will not change after that image changes on the disk. Therefore your image should be ready when you call these lines. If image will change after the window is loaded (or these two lines are executed), you need to recall the method again.

Comment: @mcy each time the button is clicked the 2 lines are called but the image doesn't change

Comment: you need to make sure that lines are called after image is prepared and exported by matlab, which may be hard to track. You can implement a `FileSystemWatcher` as in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx so that the two lines are called whenever target image file changes.

Comment: I managed to save the figure in a different location, using:
    saveas(gcf, 'C:\    \hist.jpg','jpg');
when I click a button in the C# winform the saved image is displayed, but when I click it again I get this error:
Cannot create output file 'C:\   \figures\hist.jpg'.
Error in => hist.m at line 14.
How to update the resulting image from the matlab?
Is it because it is already opened in C# so Matlab can't create it??

Comment: I'm guessing you have created your own function `hist`, as Matlab's `hist` does not have anything on line 14... so what does your function do at line 14?

Comment: @ RPM at line 14 the line saveas(gcf, 'C:\ \hist.jpg','jpg'); to save the figure in the new folder

Comment: Yes, in that case your error seems to be because the file is already open, or write access is restricted for some other reason.

Comment: Ok, then who to release the image that is already opened in the C# for the Matlab to re-save??

Comment: Just had a play - try calling `picturebox2.image.dispose` before calling the matlab dll.

Comment: @ RPM thanks alot that really helped :)